# Server Response HTTP

Tags: http, tcp

Here below is a response from the server and i wonder where i can see the TCP connection policy with which the server responds?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Connection: Keep-Alive 
Date: Sun, 20 Sep 2020 12:34:56 GMT 
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat) 
Content-Length: 286 
Cache-control: public, max-age=600
Keep-Alive: timeout=8, max=120
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 

more data...
```

Comment: What do you mean by "TCP connection policy"?

Comment: What does this says about Keep-Alive!

Comment: Are you looking for an explanation of this Keep-Alive response header? Or is there something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does this says about Keep-Alive!

From [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Keep-Alive):

- **timeout**: indicating the minimum amount of time an idle connection has to be kept opened (in seconds). Note that timeouts longer than the TCP timeout may be ignored if no keep-alive TCP message is set at the transport level.
- **max**: indicating the maximum number of requests that can be sent on this connection before closing it. Unless 0, this value is ignored for non-pipelined connections as another request will be sent in the next response. An HTTP pipeline can use it to limit the pipelining.

Comment: Note that these parameters are only defined in an Internet-Draft that expired many years ago. Browser support should not be relied on, even if all major browsers supposedly support them. Of course this whole header is not valid for HTTP/2.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: This is a HTTP/1 response. Surely it is not valid for HTTP/2. As for being from an long expired draft - good point.

Comment: What is this not valid any longer??

Comment: @john: The keep-alive header you see was proposed but never standardized. Still based on the linked documentation it seems to be implemented in many browsers.